# Great blogs site resources/tutorial for Wordpress Developers?

Tags: plugins, theme-development

I sometimes learn a few tricks from wordpress blog tutorial sites and its great that some of the people in this field , share what they know about working around with coding around wordpress.

Im just wondering do some of you know blog sites that are catering quality wordpress tutorial posts (like working around in the API, theme development , plugin development , articles) .

I know.... there are thousands of them, 
so I wanted to know if you have list of the best sites so far you know that do this. Probably the sites you bookmarked and visit regularly.

any suggestions will be cool

Answer (score 1):

Some good ones I read:

- http://www.wprecipes.com
- http://www.smashingmagazine.com usually has some good stuff. You might find more under their 'network posts'
- http://net.tutsplus.com
- http://www.catswhocode.com/blog/
- http://wpcandy.com/

Answer (score 1):

Here are some more:

- http://wp-snippets.com/
- http://wpsnipp.com/
- http://wpengineer.com/
- http://wptricks.net/

Answer (score 1):

[Justin Tadlock](http://justintadlock.com/tags/wordpress) regularly writes quality articles on WordPress development. He's also one of the authors of the "[Professional WordPress Plugin Development](http://justintadlock.com/plugindevbook)" book.

Answer (score 0):

I really like Chris Coyier's work. One of his blogs is [CSS tricks](http://css-tricks.com/). He has done some [excellent videos](http://www.lynda.com/WordPress-3-tutorials/creating-and-editing-custom-themes/67160-2.html) for Lynda's website, and is a [*good* writer](http://digwp.com/chris-coyier/).

Answer (score 0):

@wpguy

WordPress Answers is quickly becoming one of the most thorough WordPress references.

> Im just wondering do some of you know
> blog sites that are catering quality
> wordpress tutorial posts (like working
> around in the API, theme development ,
> plugin development , articles) .

Start by going through some of the tag archives here.

- ## [theme-development](/questions/tagged/theme-development)
- ## [plugin-development](/questions/tagged/plugin-development)
- ## [api](/questions/tagged/api)